# Is there a way to adjust H264 profile level in the Ozeki VoIP SIP SDK?

Tags: sip, h.264, codec, sdp, ozeki

Currently developing a softphone application using Ozeki's VoIP SIP SDK. Facing an issue where calls initiated by the SDK using H264 codec do not specify any profile-level-id in the SIP Invite message. This results in some callees defaulting to extremely low profile levels such as 1.1 (42000B) which is 176x144 resolution. The same callees called by a softphone that does provide a profile level return much better quality video.

[Here is the part of the packet capture that shows the lack of H264 profile-level-id.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaPAJ.png)

I am wondering if there are any means to provide a profile level in the SDK that is 3.1 (42001F) or higher. I have tried creating new H264 codec definitions but couldn't attach them to the softphone model. Any help or ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up manually editing the SDP message to insert a profile-level-id parameter in hex values. The SDK has the ISDPMessageManipulator interface to allow intercepting incoming and outgoing messages.